# ICMP Packets not being sent with raw socket in C

Tags: c, ip, raw-sockets

I have a program that attempts to use raw sockets to send an ICMP packet in C. However, everytime I send an ICMP packet, I receive an error from `sendto` stating, `Invalid argument.`

Here's the main portion:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 3)
     {
            fprintf(stderr, "Usage: ./main [src] [dst]\n");
            return -1;
     }

    struct sockaddr_in src, dst;
    memset(&src, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
    memset(&dst, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));

    inet_pton(AF_INET, argv[1], &src.sin_addr);
    inet_pton(AF_INET, argv[2], &dst.sin_addr);

    int s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_RAW);
    if (s == -1)
     {
            perror("socket");
            return -1;
     }


    void *pkt = create_pkt(&src, &dst, IPPROTO_ICMP);
    if (!pkt)
     {
            close(s);
            return -1;
     }

    send_pkt(s, pkt, sizeof(ICMP) + sizeof(IP), &dst);
    return 0;
}
```

Here's the function where the error happens:

```
void send_pkt(int s, void *pkt,
        int size, struct sockaddr_in *dst)
{
        if (sendto(s, pkt, size, 0,
                (struct sockaddr *) dst, sizeof(struct sockaddr)) == -1)
         {
                perror("sendto");
                return;
         }
}
```

I know I have raw sockets enabled on my system (I'm using Ubuntu 16.04) and I've also experimented with the values in `dst` including the IP destination address, but nothing has resulted in significant change. As a result, I've left `dst->sin_port = 0` and `dst->sin_family = 0`.

If anyone could shed light as to why this isn't working, I would appreciate it.

Comment: You must set `sin_family` to `AF_INET` on both `src` and `dst`.

Comment: The purpose of `src` is to convert the string form of the IP address in `argv[1]` (passed by the user) to a unsigned 4-byte integer. It is not used in the sending process in anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, with raw sockets, that `sendto` will return an error if any of the fields in the IP header are incorrect. In my case, I switched the positioning of the IHL and the version (I had combined them into one field because of endian issues). So, moral of the story: If you receive a `sendto: Invalid argument` error for a raw socket, be sure to check the IP header, not just your destination structure for `sendto`.